# Difficulty in forming a proper matrix for applying SVD Method on a pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataset.

```
|| sin || main_cat || also_view ||
==================================
|| B00520G7AU || 91 || [B07D6DDL1N, B07GXYLRRF, B008FR8UMU, B01N5XYE6M] ||
|| B003SK8V9G || 86 || [B01G7S0BX4, B000VXDHPG] ||
```

(the | and = is just the formatting I did here to show it as a table, ignore them)

I am facing problems in converting each of these objects to `strings` and `lists` respectively. The main_cat column is `integer` while others show up as objects even after trying functions like tolist(), tostring(), etc etc.

Because of which I cannot reshape the dataset.
I wish to apply SVD.

I wish to generate a matrix with `sin` as `index` and `column`, and entries of also_view as values present in matrix.

Could someone guide me with syntax of how I could move forward from here?

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can transform your data as space (or tab or pipe) separated by manual text find and replace:

- Find "||" and replace with "".
- Find ", " and replace with "".
- Find "  " (multiple continuous spaces) and replace with " " (single blank space).
- Import dataset using:

  `pd.read_csv('file.txt', delimiter=' ', index_col='sin')`

Comment: oh non ono! You got me wrong. the || is a markdown formatting I added for distinguishing the rows and columns. It's 3 columns, and around 300,000 rows. I got the dataframe. I want to make a matrix out of it.